using jHipster how to control generation of the target folder structure and place files n those instead of what structure jhipster gives by default
While generating springboot with mlementation for CRUD support for a Entity named Customer.
I wantto control and customize the folder structure, how to achieve that.
I tried understand and write customization using modiles and blueprints but its not very clear steps

What is the structure you'd like it to be and what does it do now?

folder structure like as follows:: controllers, entity, clients , consumer etc. btw folder structure is an example to start with but I want lot of customization requirements like dont want any of the code which is generated for logging, excptions, security and want to use my platforms capabilities (via my frameworks) .  I want main entity related code and rest al to customize. I want reuse those wonderful JDL capabilites,
